# Having Problem in Getting information from Spotify Api

Tags: node.js, api, spotify

I am having a 401 error on retrieving information from the SpotifyApi. even after I have save the access token. The following is my code snippet.

```
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err.message);
  });

spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE').then(
    function(data) {
      console.log('Artist albums', data.body);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

My terminal output is

```
[Error [WebapiError]: Unauthorized] { statusCode: 401 }
The access token expires in 3600
The access token is BQC5dKw5ArfFn7t-NgutgOOCRXoiWLvP6i9N0sUQj4RdaTsQYvZXN26kMU47EfS2jM4Lo1rwHdLLovo1aag
```

However, the code ran well if I move `.getArtist()` in `.clientCredentialsGrant()`

```
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);

    spotifyApi.getArtist('2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3')
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('Artist information', data.body);
    }, function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });

  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong when retrieving an access token', err.message);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the token in correctly?

Comment: I think so, I was following the documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node